# How can I get Word to open in draft view automatically?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word

I am using Word for Mac 2011 (Version 14.1.2) and I would like it to default open files in `draft view` as opposed to `print view`.  It is not obvious to me what settings to change to get this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The views are not set global, but per document. If you open the document and save it in draft view, it will reopen in draft view. Also, once you selected draft on new document, word seems to default to that for new docs on startup.

You can find a whole thread on the topic here:

[Microsoft Answers KB: Set Default View to Draft](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macword/word-2011-set-default-view-to-draft/d1f76573-31f5-4c67-8a00-bbe030362bc0?msgId=6bd6b7ff-7832-448a-b196-62ca57f94f89)

Answer (score 0):

I can't confirm Word 2011, but at least in Word 2013 and 2016, you can add the following macro to your Normal template:

```
Sub AutoOpen()
    ActiveWindow.View.Draft = True
End Sub
```

To create new documents in draft view:

```
Sub AutoNew()
    ActiveWindow.View.Draft = True
End Sub
```

I had the same question, and found the answer I provided above [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_365hp-word/how-can-i-make-word-2013-open-in-draft-view-by/).